# Livewire show variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a variable $login that will contain data.

```
public $account;
public $login;

public function getAccountOrder($id)
{
   $this->account = Buys::findOrFail($id);
   $this->login = $this->account->accounts;
}
public function render()
{
   $buys = Buys::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
   return view('livewire.profile', compact('buys'));
}
```

Modal opening (modal in same view that all content)

```
<a href="#" data-remodal-target="modal-account-email" wire:click="getAccountOrder({{ $buy->id }})" class="thing-item__link"></a>
```

In modal displays this variable, but it does not display the required data. But in livewire helper (google extension) i can see data that i need to display

```
 <div wire:ignore.self class="remodal remodal--prize" data-remodal-id="modal-account-email" aria-labelledby="modalRandTitle" aria-describedby="modalRandDesc" tabindex="-1">
    <button type="button" class="remodal__close" data-remodal-action="close">
        <svg><use xlink:href="#svg-btn_modal_close"></use></svg>
    </button>
    <div class="modal__header" id="modalRandTitle">Your login</div>
    <div class="modal__content" id="modalRandDesc">
        <div class="modal__accounts">
            <div class="modal__accounts-row">
                <div class="input__box">
                    <div class="input__box-btn" data-btn-clipboard="{{ $login }}" onclick="copyToClipboard('{{ $login }}')">
                        <svg class="svg-btn_clipboard"><use xlink:href="#svg-btn_clipboard"></use></svg>
                        <svg class="svg-btn_check"><use xlink:href="#svg-btn_check"></use></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input__box-field">
                        <div class="input__box-label">Login</div>
                        <div class="input__box-value">{{ $login }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i render this variable in livewire component?

Comment: It would help to see more of the actual code you have. Is the modal in the same view as the livewire component? What value is shown/not shown?

Comment: Updated! I will be grateful for your help

Comment: $this->account->accounts ... "accounts" is just a property on Buy model or is an elocuent relationship result?

Comment: just a property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want the changed value of `$login` gets reflected in the javascript on the page. if this is the case you need to dispatch an event from your `getAccountOrder` function and catch it on the page with js.

something like this:

```
public function getAccountOrder($id)
{
   $this->account = Buys::findOrFail($id);
   $this->login = $this->account->accounts;
   $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('yourEventName', ['value'=> $this->login]);

}
```

then on the something like this should be added:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('yourEventName', (e) => {
    //do something with the value 
    console.log(e.detail.value);
  });
</script>
```